# $T:X \to Y$ continuous linear map between Banach Spaces with adjoint $T^{*}:Y^{*} \to X^{*}$ show that if $T^{*}(Y^{*})$ closed then $T(X)$ closed.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I'm trying to solve the following problem in functional analysis:

Let $T:X \to Y$ be a continuous linear map between Banach Spaces with adjoint $T^{*}:Y^{*} \to X^{*}$ show that if $T^{*}(Y^{*})$ closed then $T(X)$ closed.

Using the open mapping theorem, I have proven the converse. i.e. $T(X)$ closed implies that $T^{*}(Y^{*})$ closed.

I have two ideas at the moment:

1. Consider the double adjoint map i.e. $T^{**}:X^{**} \to Y^{**}$ and try to show that $T(X) \subset T^{**}(X^{**})$ closed. Here I've made the identification of $Y$ as a subset of $Y^{**}$ using the evaluation map.
2. Try to prove the contrapositive. i.e. Suppose that $T(X)$ is not open and try to construct a sequence in $T^{*}(Y^{*})$ with limit in $X^{*} - T^{*}(Y^{*})$.

I've not been able to follow-through with either of these attempts. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This is called Banach's Closed Raneg Theorem. It is non-trivial.